# Data structure for Expandible and Collapsible Sections in UITableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

I have a UITableViewController which shows a list of transactions sorted by date. This is for a personal finance / banking-style app.

What I want to achieve: The section headers (which show the date) should expand/collapse when tapped.

I'm using Realm database to store my transaction data.

I'm a beginner programmer and I've tried to google a solution but I'm stuck trying to create data structure to track whether a section is opened or closed.

I've tried following this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8k9E1gQ_qg&) but I get stuck at 12:00.

**Realm model:**

```swift
class Transaction: Object {
    @objc dynamic var amount: Float = 0
    @objc dynamic var toFrom: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var category : String = ""
    @objc dynamic var date: Date? = nil
    @objc dynamic var note: String = ""
}
```

**Table View Controller:**

```swift
class TransactionsViewController : UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var transactions2TableView: UITableView!

    let realm = try! Realm()

    var groupedTransactions = [Date:Results<Transaction>]()
    var transactionDates = [Date]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadTransactions()
    }

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int { 
        return transactionDates.count
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            return groupedTransactions[transactionDates[section]]!.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell2", for: indexPath)
        let itemsForDate = groupedTransactions[transactionDates[indexPath.section]]!

        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(Array(itemsForDate)[indexPath.row].toFrom)"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(String(describing: convertToCurrency(Array(itemsForDate)[indexPath.row].amount)!))"

        return cell

    }

func loadTransactions() {

        let transaction = realm.objects(Transaction.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "date", ascending: false)

        //Find each unique day for which a Transaction exists in your Realm
        transactionDates = transaction.reduce(into: [Date](), { results, currentTransaction in
            let date = currentTransaction.date!
            let beginningOfDay = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: Calendar.current.component(.year, from: date), month: Calendar.current.component(.month, from: date), day: Calendar.current.component(.day, from: date), hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0))!
            let endOfDay = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: Calendar.current.component(.year, from: date), month:     Calendar.current.component(.month, from: date), day: Calendar.current.component(.day, from: date), hour: 23, minute: 59, second: 59))!

            //Only add the date if it doesn't exist in the array yet
            if !results.contains(where: { addedDate->Bool in
                return addedDate >= beginningOfDay && addedDate <= endOfDay
            }) {
                results.append(beginningOfDay)
            }
        })

        //Filter each transaction in realm based on their date property and assign the results to the dictionary
        groupedTransactions = transactionDates.reduce(into: [Date:Results<Transaction>](), { results, date in
            let beginningOfDay = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: Calendar.current.component(.year, from: date), month: Calendar.current.component(.month, from: date), day: Calendar.current.component(.day, from: date), hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0))!
            let endOfDay = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: Calendar.current.component(.year, from: date), month: Calendar.current.component(.month, from: date), day: Calendar.current.component(.day, from: date), hour: 23, minute: 59, second: 59))!
            results[beginningOfDay] = realm.objects(Transaction.self).filter("date >= %@ AND date <= %@", beginningOfDay, endOfDay)
        })


        self.transactionsTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: The question is a little unclear as the expandable and collapsable function in a tableView is unrelated to data stored in Realm. In other words, if you run a query for all of the realm objects for a given month, the tableView headers would be populated based on the objects dates available and when expanding, the rows that are shown are populated from those same objects. What exactly are you asking? Can you clarify what the issue is?

Comment: Hi Jay. I'm just trying to make my sections expand and collapse when I tap on them.

Comment: So the question is unrelated to Realm or Realm structures? If so, you can remove that tag and edit the title as Realm has nothing to do with UI elements. There are a lot of tutorials that cover how to expand a row in a UITableView, here's a pretty good one [How to created expandable table Views](https://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/)

Comment: I guess it's not related to the underlying Realm database, sorry I'm a newbie - I'll update my question. I was following the video I linked and I got stuck at the part where the data structure was updated to track whether each section was expanded/collapsed. I can't figure out how to implement something similar for my app.